# removing duplicates on a subset of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have the below data in a dataframe df:

```
Date    Symbol     ClosingPrice     Weight
1/13/2016   A      36.52            -0.000002
1/13/2016   A      37               -0.001
1/14/2016   A      36.35            -0.000002
1/15/2016   A      36.35            -0.000002
1/13/2016   AA      7.01             0.000112
1/14/2016   AA      7.01             0.000112
1/15/2016   AA      6.7              0.000112
1/13/2016   AAC    15.91            -0.000004
1/13/2016   AAC    15.91            -0.0002
1/13/2016   AAC    18                0.0002
```

I want to filter out duplicates where the Data and Symbol are equal with no reference to the values of Closing price or Weight

the final result should look like this

```
Date    Symbol     ClosingPrice     Weight
1/13/2016   A      36.52            -0.000002
1/14/2016   A      36.35            -0.000002
1/15/2016   A      36.35            -0.000002
1/13/2016   AA      7.01             0.000112
1/14/2016   AA      7.01             0.000112
1/15/2016   AA      6.7              0.000112
1/13/2016   AAC    15.91            -0.000004
```

I wish to keep the first occurrence  if a duplicate exisits

I tried this `df2=df.drop_duplicates(['Date','Symbol'], keep='first')`
but it did not work.

Thanks for any assistance on this

Comment: Your attempt seems correct. Did you get an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: I think there are some whitespaces in `Symbol` column, so you need [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) -  `df['Symbol'] = df.Symbol.str.strip()`, because your code works perfectly.

Comment: What didnt work? what was the output?

Comment: It was me, I had white spaces in the data, once removed all was fine.